# Spring Boot - WebFlux keep context of result with id when running i parallel

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Using Spring boot Web client to request JSON from a REST API, the response body from the server is stored in a simple `Map`. The request to the server contains an ID, but this isn't included in the response, but is required to interpret the response.

I would want to include the id in the result of the parallel call, so instead of instead of `List<Map> data` should it be `Map<UUID,Map> data` or similar. So the response from the server is paired with the id that was used to get the response.

```
        List<Map> data = Flux.fromIterable(ids)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .flatMap(this::callAPI).sequential().collectList().block();
```

```
    private Mono<Map> callAPI(UUID id) {
        return client.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .path("/{id}/")
                .build(id))
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Map.class);
    }
```

Comment: why dont you try `collectMap` instead of `collectList`

Comment: @ThomasAndolf How would I supply the `UUID id` into the `collectMap`?

Comment: By not returning a `Mono<Map>` from your `callApi` function. Return a `Map` and the `Id` in wrapper object that you can later use to remap to your wanted structure `.bodyToMono(Map.class).flatMap(map -> { return Mono.just(new Response(id, map)); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @ThomasAndolf comment

> By not returning a `Mono<Map>` from your `callApi` function. Return a `Map` and the `Id` in wrapper object that you can later use to remap to your wanted structure `.bodyToMono(Map.class).flatMap(map -> { return Mono.just(new Response(id, map)); });` – Thomas Andolf 22 hours ago